# Can't get response from webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, json.net

This is my code in WebService.cs

```
private void ResponseData(string strJSON)
{
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.Write(strJSON);
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void login(string login, string password)
{
    try
    {
        objda.loginid = login;
        objda.pass = password;
        ds = objda.getadminbyusernamepass();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ResponseData(@"[{""result"":""success""}]");
        }
        else
        {
            ResponseData(@"[{""result"":""failure""}]");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ResponseData(@"[{""result"":""error"""+ex.ToString()+"}]");
    }
}
```

where `objda` is an object that accesses data through the a stored procedure.

This is the aspx page:

```
 <form runat="server" id="form1">
     <div>
         <input type="text" id="login" runat="server" /><br />
         <input type="text" runat="server" id="password"/>
         <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="sendrequest();" />
     </div>
 </form>

<script>
    function sendrequest() {
        var a = $("#login").val();
        var b = $("#password").val();
        console.log(rowID);
        $.ajax({
            url: "WebService.asmx/login",
            data: '{"login":"' + a+ '","password":"' + b+ '"}',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('error: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + thrownError);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

I get error 500 undefined on button press. Also instead of showing `alert='success'`, I would like to access the value of result and show it. Any suggestions will  be helpful.

Comment: please check the network tab in console & share what the error description is?

Comment: Try adding [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] to your class. This will allow your method to be called from client side. Here is the walkthrough that help me. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb532367(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @balaji marimuthu Error 500(Internal Server (Error) type=xhr initiator=jquery-1.4.1.min.js:130.

Comment: @rexroxm seems like you've shared the different message, it should be shown the message description in Network-> Response like "Parameter name invalid/missing"

Answer (score 0):

The way login(login,password) method is written, it says, the arguments can be supplied by using query string. But in your ajax call, you have constructed the data to be json which is not correct. Try changing your method signature to

```
    public class CustomerModel
    {
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }

    public void login(CustomerModel customerlogin)
    {
        // Code
    }
```